# Error ExceptionInInitializerError when creating instances of opencv classes - Mat, RectVector and CascadeClassifier

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm trying to make face recognition Java app for studies. Basing on tutorial from YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3x7ofnQJMo4&t=2180s
I'm stuck on ending of third part of tutorial (linked above) with error while creating instance of opencv related classes like:

```
    Mat cameraImage = new Mat();
    CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier(HAAR_XML);
    BytePointer mem = new BytePointer();
    RectVector detectedFaces = new RectVector();
```

On every of above lines i reaching an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.company.loginpanel.main(loginpanel.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

I can skip errors by skipping creating instance, like below:

```
    Mat cameraImage;
    CascadeClassifier cascade;
    BytePointer mem;
    RectVector detectedFaces;
```

Obviously, it crashes in further lines, due no objects under variables.

No matter where in code I'm trying to create instances, it crashes.

Please find full code on my GitHub: https://github.com/shanstoni/FaceRecognition

I have tried already:

- changing java libs for older versions
- changed sdk from 12 to 1.8
- loading opencv from code:  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture webSource = null;
    Mat cameraImage = new Mat();
    CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier(HAAR_XML);
    BytePointer mem = new BytePointer();
    RectVector detectedFaces = new RectVector();
}
```

Here is full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.company.loginpanel.main(loginpanel.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.checkPlatform(Loader.java:970)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1074)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1036)
    at org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.AbstractArray.<clinit>(AbstractArray.java:18)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include `openblas-platform.jar`, `openblas.jar`, and the corresponding native jar for your platform from `javacv-platform`.